# Is safe to not call GC.KeepAlive() in this scenario?

Tags: c#, .net

let's say we have the following code running in release build:

```
class SomeClass
{
  // This field is initialized somewhere in the constructor (not shown here).
  public SomeOtherClass Value;

  ...
}

class SomeOtherClass {
  ...
  public void Call() {
     ...
  }
}
...

static void Main()
{
  SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
  SomeOtherMethod(obj.Value);
  ...
}

static void SomeOtherMethod(SomeOtherClass value) {
  ... // do sth else first
  value.Call();   // value is a reference that points to `obj.Value` object in heap
}
```

I saw code like this all the time and at that time I was not familiar with how GC works.
But now I know that the garbage collect may collect obj just after the runtime has retrieved obj.Value i.e. before SomeOtherMethod() is even called. So there is a chance (although unlikely, but still possible) that when `SomeOtherMethod` execute and before manipulate `obj.Value` the argument, `obj` has been marked as unreachable (therefore its member `Value` is also marked as unreachable) and collected by GC and their memory is recliamed, so it is illegal for `SomeOtherMethod` to access `Value`.

So I think a solution is to add `GC.KeepAlive(obj)` or `GC.KeepAlive(obj.Value)` as:

```
void MyMethod()
{
  SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();
  SomeOtherMethod(obj.Value);
  ...
  GC.KeepAlive(obj);   //  or GC.KeepAlive(obj.Value);
}
```

But I don't see many people(senior developer) doing this, and the code always running correctly without throwing any exception. So is my understanding incorrect or CLR has a workaround on this?

Comment: The GC system is built to collect objects when they're no longer reachable. You *don't have to help the system in that analysis*. `obj.Value`, once read, does not depend on `obj` staying around.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever but `obj.Value` is a reference that points to an object in the heap, if the object is collected by GC, how can we continue call its function member?

Comment: You don't need to baby sit the GC like this. If your using managed objects just let it do it's job and pretend it doesn't exist (99% of the time at least)

Comment: @amjad "but `obj.Value` is a reference that points to an object in the heap" that's a very nuanced claim; what `obj.Value` is depends on `obj.Value`, which you haven't shown; `obj.Value` could just be an `int`; it could be an *entirely different object*, or it could be itself (`return this;`) - but that's fine: the GC knows how to handle references; I would agree that `ref obj.Value` is probably an interior managed pointer inside an object on the heap, but: the GC understands managed pointers, so again: no issue. Either `obj` being collected is irrelevant, or `obj` *won't be* collected.

Comment: "obj.Value is a reference that points to an object in the heap" - if it is, it's a reference to some other object (whatever the type of `Value` is, if it's a reference type). It's not a reference to (part of) `obj`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think I got your point. the object (referenced by `obj.Value`) won't be collected by GC even though its containing SomeOtherClass instance gets collected, is it what you mean? I

Comment: @amjad if you mean "even though its containing `SomeClass` instance gets collected", then: yes - although when talking about references, "containing" is not really a good word - anything can point anywhere if you try hard enough; there is no logical "containment" except that which we impose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `obj.Value` has been read, the *value* of that (which could be a reference, or a primitive/struct) is *copied* (to where doesn't matter; note that in the case of a reference it is only the *reference* that is copied, not the object that it refers to). At that point, it *doesn't matter* whether `obj` is collected - the copy of the value is independent.

Note that if you were using ref-return properties or naked fields with `SomeOtherMethod(ref obj.Value)`, then things are *slightly* different, but in that case: we still know that the GC can follow managed pointers (aka `ref`), and if necessary this would *keep the object alive*.

So no, you don't need `GC.KeepAlive`. The times you *need* `GC.KeepAlive` are very niche and exotic (and usually involve things like finalizers and indirect (non-reference) relationships between data); in most everyday scenarios: the GC does what you want without needing your input.

Comment: I have added some extra code to explain it better, if `obj` is collected then `obj.Value` is also collected, then `SomeOtherMethod` cannot execute?

Comment: @amjad your edit doesn't change anything: once `obj.Value` has been read, you have a *copy* of that value - you're not looking at the value inside `obj` any more; note I *did* edit in a mention of `ref`, which *might* allow you to be looking at the same value, but in that case: you *still* don't need `GC.KeepAlive`, because the `ref` keeps the object alive

Comment: @amjad to use an example: you ask me for Fred's phone number; I look it up on my phone, and tell it you; now **my** phone gets lost/stolen/broken/recalled/whatever. This doesn't affect you: you still have Fred's phone number - the copy scribbled on the back of an envelope (or whatever) is not impacted *even slightly* by the fact that my phone is gone

Comment: sorry I'm really confused, when we pass an argument, if the argument type is an class, then we pass by reference, so there won't be a new class instance created  as  a copy, `SomeOtherClass` is class, not struct

Comment: @amjad "then we pass by reference" - no we absolutely do not; we pass a reference **by value**; this is a *completely different thing*; to be passing a reference by reference, you would need to use the `ref` keyword (as in: `ref obj.Value`), and the GC *knows how to handle that without your help*. Pedantic minutiae: you can also *implicitly* pass a reference by reference if the receiving parameter is marked as `in`, but again: that is (more or less) the same scenario as passing `ref obj.Value`, and the GC knows what to do

Comment: @amjad and don't worry, the semantics of this (whether you're passing a value or a reference, and whether you are passing it by-value or by-reference) are a big stumbling point that confuses many people - you're not alone here or being particularly dense or anything like that - it is a **very** common misunderstanding. Key point: even if you're passing a reference, you're usually passing it **by value**. If you're familiar with C, this is `Foo*` vs `Foo**`

Comment: @amjad additional point to emphasize: even if we *were* passing the reference by-reference, again: the GC knows how to handle that  (as long as we don't use `unsafe`/`fixed`/etc) - you *don't need to deal with it*

Comment: maybe it is better to have a concrete example. Let's say that `obj.Value`  is stored at 0x0123,and a reference that refers to this object in heap, the reference points to 0x0123 (where  `obj.Value` is)  in heap. Now  I pass this reference to `SomeOtherMethod(SomeOtherClass value)`, so the argument `value` also points to 0x0123 in the heap, here is my question, when the `obj.Value` in 0x0123 is collected by GC, `SomeOtherMethod` still tries to access 0x0123 in heap, isn't it a problem?

Comment: @amjad details **really matter here**. Do you mean that the *field backing* `obj.Value` is stored at 0x0123 (with the object we're talking about as `obj` being, say, 0x0100 thru 0x0140), or do you mean that when de-referenced, the field at `obj.Value` *refers* to another object, which is at `0x0123`? the difference is huge, and matters. Basically, reading `obj.Value` is a dereference operation, and the field location *is not exposed to the consumer* - only the dereferenced value (which can itself be a reference). So once you've read it, it *doesn't matter* if `obj` goes away.

Comment: @amjad the only time you're actually getting the *field location* is when using `ref obj.Value` (or `in obj.Value` or `out obj.Value`, which are both just fancy forms of `ref` to the compiler), and in that scenario: the fact that an interior managed pointer to `obj` now exists in an active stack-frame **is enough to keep `obj` alive**.

Comment: @amjad or to put it another way; are you talking about the *address* of `obj.Value` being 0x0123, or the *value* of `obj.Value` being 0x0123; because `obj.Value` fetches the *value*; `ref obj.Value` fetches the address

Comment: Hi, I think I have figure it out  why GC.KeepAlive() is not needed because the the object (referenced by obj.Value) won't be collected by GC even though its containing SomeOtherClass instance gets collected. if that object won't be collected, of course we don't need GC.KeepAlive(). But it also bring another question, what if `SomeClass` has a `Finalize` method that call Dispose() mehotd on SomeOtherClass, that's interesting.

Comment: @amjad I'm not sure that's entirely right, but: it could just be phrasing - but if I may simplify: once `obj.Value` has been read, `obj` can *absolutely* be collected while `SomeOtherMethod` runs; nothing keeps `obj` alive, but the value we copied from `obj.Value` will keep `SomeOtherClass` alive; is that what you were saying? if so: yes. If the finalizer of `SomeClass` touches another object via `.Value`, then yes: bad things could happen, and yes `GC.KeepAlive(obj);` would stop that - but: in that scenario, the real bug is that `SomeClass` *touched another object in the finalizer* (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) which is something that a finalizer simply *should not do*, and is not what finalizers are for. The bug there is in `~SomeClass()`, quite simply. Finalizers are *incredibly* rare, and should only really clean up *unmanaged* resources owned by the type (equally rare), although at a push I'd allow "static counter and static logging, in a DEBUG build, for tracking purposes". Touching other objects in a finalizer is very risky - for all you know, the things you have references to *have already themselves been finalized* (as in: they got collected in the same pass)

Comment: I also don't quite get it why you cannot access `Value` member object in `~SomeClass()`, it is true that both `SomeClass` instance and `SomeOtherClass` instance will be marked as unreachable and their Finalize method will be called, but when  `SomeClass` instance call its Finalize method,  `SomeOtherClass` instance still live in the heap, it will only be collected in the next GC, before that, `~SomeClass()` can still access its member object?

Comment: @amjad often, two objects with a reference between them will both be marked as non-reachable in the same collection sweep, and they will be finalized in the same sweep; the GC simply starts at the "roots", and touches *everything it can*; anything that doesn't get touched: can be collected. So if the "parent" object wasn't reachable, usually neither will the "child" object be. During the finalizer *yes* it is still technically on the heap, but the order in which finalizers get executed is non-deterministic. You don't know what order they will be run in (or even *if* they will run).

Comment: @amjad because of this - and perhaps more fundamentally, **because of the intended purpose of finalizers**, you simply aren't meant to touch *any other objects* in a finalizer, *especially* if you're reaching those objects via fields on the instance being finalized. Honestly, that's just not the job of a finalizer. Use `Dispose()` instead. If a consumer fails to call `Dispose()`: that's their bug, not yours.

Comment: as you mentioned that  "they will be finalized in the same sweep;". From what I recall how Finalize works is, there is a dedicated thread to call type's Finalize method, so at this point of time, those two objects are still reachable, since  they are still in freachable queue, you might say that  `SomeOtherClass` 's Finalize method will get executed first, but that's OK,  `SomeOtherClass` instance will only get collected by next GC, and  `SomeClass` instance 's Finalize method wiil normally executed before next GC occurs. it is still OK for `~SomeClass() ` to access its member

Comment: Continued from above. The only exception is that SomeClass instance 's Finalize method is blocked for a long time(for example, use `Thread.Sleep` first then access its `SomeOtherClass` member, because the thread is sleep for some times, the next GC occurs and collect the its `SomeOtherClass` member object, when `~SomeClass()` wakes up and  continue to access `SomeOtherClass` member which has been destoryed. I understand this scenorio could be rare, but since it might still happen, so we shouldn't access member object from Finalize, Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @amjad what is "ok" is complex; I have to write in the general case, and in the general case *you don't know* what `SomeOtherClass`'s finalizer is going to do - it could, for example, reset some key fields after doing cleanup, which make it throw an exception when accessed later from `SomeClass`'s finalizer - and throwing an exception in a finalizer means process death; if you use `Thread.Sleep` in a finalizer, you need to be shot. Basically, I'm saying "don't dance in minefields", and you're arguing about "what ifs" - no: stop doing that; you (and I) *will* get it wrong and you *will* lose.

Comment: I raise a new question in a different post that explains in details, could you have a look? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67058713/different-scenarios-when-writing-a-finalize-method-that-accesses-other-objects-w  I'm not arguing about "what ifs", I certain won't dance in minefields, but I want to make sure my understanding on Finalize method is correct, by doing that, I have to dance in minefields just for now, not in real life