# Different scenarios when writing a Finalize method that accesses other objects whose type defines a Finalize method

Tags: c#, .net

I'm reading a book (CLR via C#) which says:

> CLR doesn’t make any guarantees as to the order in which Finalize methods are called. So, you should avoid writing a Finalize method that accesses other objects whose type defines a Finalize method; those other objects could have been finalized already. However, it is perfectly OK to access value type instances or reference type objects that do not define a Finalize method.

I kind of get the idea but I'm not 100% sure why it is dangerous, so I will picture some different scenarios to verify whether or not my understanding on Finalize is correct

Let's say we have the following code:

```
class ClassA
{
  public ClassB Item;
  public ClassA(ClassB item) { this.Item = item };
  ~ClassA {
     ...  // might contain some time-consuming operations
     item.Call();
  }
}

class ClassB {
  public void Call() {

  }
   ~ClassB {
     Console.Write("Finalize run");   // simple statment, error-free
  }
}
...

static void Main()
{
  ClassB b = new Class B();
  ClassA a= new ClassA(b);
  ...   // do sth else
  GC.Collect();   // first GC
  ...   // do sth else
  GC.Collect();   // second GC
  ...   // do sth else
}
```

We know that The CLR uses a special, high-priority dedicated thread(let's call it Fthread) to call Finalize methods, and let's assume only two manual GC occurs, no auto triggered GC occurs.

So after first GC occurs, `a` and `b` marked as unreachable

Case OK 1:
Fthread calls `~ClassA`, followed by `~ClassB`, `b` exists on the heap before second GC occurs

Case OK 2:
Fthread calls `~ClassB`, followed by `~ClassA`, `b` exists on the heap before second GC occurs

Case Not OK:

Fthread calls `~ClassB`, followed by `~ClassA`, but `~ClassA` executes some time-confuming operations before executing Call() on its member `b`. Second GC occurs, b is collected by GC, `~ClassA` finishes the time-consuming operations, start to execute Call() on `b`, but `b` no longer exists in heap.

Based on the Case Not OK example, although it is rare, we still need to avoid writing a Finalize method that accesses other objects whose type defines a Finalize method. Is my understanding correct? I certainly won't writing a Finalize method that accesses other objects whose type defines a Finalize method, I know what is "ok" is complex; All I want to do is make sure my understanding is correct so that I know my understanding on Finalize method is correct

Comment: Just out of curiosity could you please share with us which book are you talking about?

Comment: [When done enough times, rare things are not rare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_truly_large_numbers). In case 3, `~ClassA` throws a `NullReference`, this is nothing to do with `ClassB` defining a finalizer also, and in fact, if it does not define one then it is *more* likely to be collected already, because all finalized objects will be promoted to from GC0 to GC1 to await finalization, whereas non-finalized objects will be collected immediately. You also have the rest of the object graph to consider, and the fact that any `IDisposable` may already be disposed.

Comment: Note that, to a first approximation, the answer to "when is it correct to write a finalizer at all" is "never". For almost all scenarios where a finalizer is appropriate (disposing unmanaged resources) a type wrapping that resource has already been written and included in the BCL and can simply be used as-is. Where not, if you have to write such a type yourself, it should be a `sealed` type with no references to any managed objects at all (finalizers or no). These more advanced scenarios then simply become irrelevant curiosities that only the implementers of the GC have to worry about.

Comment: @Charlieface I just think this question twice and found my previous approach is not correct. Because if it is wrong to let a type to access a reference member in the type's Finalize when the reference member has Finalize, then why it is OK if reference member doesn't have Finalize. I post a different question, could you have a look please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093620/why-it-is-ok-to-a-type-to-access-a-reference-member-in-the-types-finalize-but-n?noredirect=1#comment118594436_67093620

Answer (score 2):

These problems are rarely interesting with trivial examples, because the problems only show in non-trivial ones, but if you want a few trivial examples:

- someone passes `null` in as `item` on the constructor; your `item.Call()` throws an exception on the finalizer thread, and your app explodes in a shower of sparks
- so you add `null` checking in `ClassA`'s constructor; someone uses `RuntimeHelpers.GetUninitializedObject` to create an instance of `ClassA` that is all zeros/nulls; your `item.Call()` throws an exception on the finalizer thread, and your app explodes in a shower of sparks
- someone leaves your `ClassB`  instance in a state that `Call` doesn't anticipate, perhaps because of an exception, or perhaps because it was disposed (or perhaps it was being accessed concurrently by two threads in ways that left it so horribly mangled that it would need dental records, or perhaps someone used reflection to poke at it); now your `item.Call()` throws an exception - sparks resume

But ultimately, there is a much more important point:

## Because you're using finalizers wrong

What you're asking about is not interesting because *that isn't the intended and correct use of finalizers*. This is a really advanced topic that is needed *almost never* (I've been using .NET since the earliest releases, and I think I might have used one, maybe two real genuine production finalizers - talking to unmanaged C/C++ APIs via P/Invoke). When you're already doing something inadvisable, asking "exactly how much can I get away with?" is the wrong question.

Comment: I just think this question twice and found my previous approach is not correct. Because if it is wrong to let a type to access a reference member in the type's Finalize when the reference member has Finalize, then why it is OK if reference member doesn't have Finalize. I post a different question, could you have a look please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67093620/why-it-is-ok-to-a-type-to-access-a-reference-member-in-the-types-finalize-but-n

Comment: @amjad it is *less bad*, because there's no chance that the finalizers have run in an unexpected order, but this is still the "dancing in a minefield". Seriously, *stop touching other objects in finalizers*; that isn't what you're meant to do in a finalizer, and it is going to cause you pain.

Comment: you mean it is less bad(still bad) when a type to access a reference member in the type's Finalize when the reference member doesn't have Finalize? But the author explicitly says it is perfectly OK to do that

Comment: @amjad which author are we talking about, in what context? citation please, so I can make a sensible comment?

Comment: The book is CLR via C# https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2224054&seqNum=3   the author says: "However, it is perfectly OK to access value type instances or reference type objects that do not define a Finalize method."

Comment: @amjad That's not quite true, it is not safe to access a reference-type field from `this` without a null check, because it may have been deleted by GC already. Obviously anything you have in local variables or static fields, and anything held by their object graphs, are OK.